# Code works on its own, but not as a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, r-package

I have a function that I made for a package that does not work anymore and I have not been able to figure out why. The point of the function is to transform a [string of hexadecimal data](https://github.com/agryt/xrfr/blob/master/inst/extdata/sample_hex.txt) to a [dataframe](https://github.com/agryt/xrfr/blob/master/inst/extdata/sample_transformed.csv) (links to examples on github). This code is quite long so instead of including it all here, here is a [link to the code on github](https://github.com/agryt/xrfr/blob/master/R/transformssd.R). When I run the code line by line it works perfectly, but when I try to use the function I get this:

```
> sample1.df <- transformssd(hex_data = sample1)
a: 1.08641362190247
a: 59.1739654541016
a: 0.32277500629425
a: 2.70198535919189
a: 0.127873212099075
a: 0.262394219636917
a: 27.9828720092773
a: 0.140874609351158
a: 0.274696856737137
a: 0.336845397949219
a: 0.452615290880203
a: 0.107537969946861
a: 0.12063916772604
a: 0.198753878474236
a: 0.521674871444702
a: 0.863220930099487
a: 0.765538036823273
Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
```

The values shown here are the values that I want to get inside my dataframe, so it appears that creating the dataframe is the problem. When running `rlang::last_error()` and `rlang::last_trace()` this is what I get:

```
> rlang::last_error()
x
+-<error/vctrs_error_subscript_type>
| Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
| x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
\-<error/vctrs_error_cast_lossy>
  Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
Backtrace:
  1. xrfr::transformssd(hex_data = sample1)
 22. vctrs:::try_catch_impl(...)
 27. vctrs:::try_catch_callback(data, NULL)
 29. vctrs:::vec_cast.integer.double(...)
 30. vctrs::maybe_lossy_cast(out, x, to, lossy, x_arg = x_arg, to_arg = to_arg)
 34. vctrs:::stop_lossy_cast(...)
 35. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

> rlang::last_trace()
x
+-<error/vctrs_error_subscript_type>
| Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
| x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
\-<error/vctrs_error_cast_lossy>
  Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-xrfr::transformssd(hex_data = sample1)
  2. | \-values.df %>% dplyr::select(a)
  3. +-dplyr::select(., a)
  4. +-dplyr:::select.data.frame(., a)
  5. | \-tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(...)), .data)
  6. |   \-tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
  7. |     +-tidyselect:::with_subscript_errors(...)
  8. |     | +-base::tryCatch(...)
  9. |     | | \-base:::tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 10. |     | |   \-base:::tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 11. |     | |     \-base:::doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 12. |     | \-tidyselect:::instrument_base_errors(expr)
 13. |     |   \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 14. |     \-tidyselect:::vars_select_eval(...)
 15. |       \-tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
 16. |         \-tidyselect:::eval_c(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
 17. |           \-tidyselect:::reduce_sels(node, data_mask, context_mask, init = init)
 18. |             \-tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(new, data_mask, context_mask)
 19. |               \-tidyselect:::as_indices_sel_impl(...)
 20. |                 \-tidyselect:::as_indices_impl(x, vars, strict = strict)
 21. |                   \-vctrs::vec_as_subscript(x, logical = "error")
 22. \-vctrs:::try_catch_impl(...)
 23.   +-base::tryCatch(try_catch_callback(data, NULL), ...)
 24.   | \-base:::tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 25.   |   \-base:::tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 26.   |     \-base:::doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 27.   \-vctrs:::try_catch_callback(data, NULL)
 28.     \-(function () ...
 29.       \-vctrs:::vec_cast.integer.double(...)
 30.         \-vctrs::maybe_lossy_cast(out, x, to, lossy, x_arg = x_arg, to_arg = to_arg)
 31.           +-base::withRestarts(...)
 32.           | \-base:::withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
 33.           |   \-base:::doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
 34.           \-vctrs:::stop_lossy_cast(...)
 35.             \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

It looks like the problem is with `dplyr::select()` somehow, but I have not been able to figure out why. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me figuring this out, thanks!

The hexadecimal data linked above can be used to test the code on.

**Edit**

I have not been able to reproduce the error in a shorter function so far, but this code does not create the dataframe that it should. Since the original problem was in creating the dataframe, I thought this might still be helpful in solving the problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magicfor)

subhex <- c("9A0F8B3F", "24B26C42", "C442A53E")

transformhex <- function(hex_string) {
  subhex <- hex_string
  magic_for(silent = TRUE)
  for (i in 1: length(subhex)) {
    a <- readBin(as.raw(strtoi(apply(matrix(strsplit(subhex,"")[[i]],2),2,paste, collapse=""), 16)), "double", size=4)
    put(a)
  }
  
  values1.df <- magic_result_as_dataframe()
  values1.df <- values1.df %>% 
    dplyr::select(a)
  
  return(values1.df)
}

> transformhex(hex_string = subhex)
          a
1  1.086414
2 59.173965
3  0.322775
```

Like the original function it shows the correct values, but does not create the dataframe. Also like before, this is only a problem when using the function, not when running the code line by line.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are not subsetting the column you want properly, indicated by this ```Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.```. On line 76, you assing the variable ```a``` to something. And on line 83 you use this variable to select something from the data frame. However, variable ```a``` is not defined in the scope of the select. ```a``` is only visible within the for loop.

Comment: I don't think the problem that you are facing requires us to go through the entire code on GitHub. Can you try to reduce the problem with smaller example so that the specific error message is generated?

Comment: @MacOS That makes sense. I have tried putting `a` outside of the loop, however I am struggling with this due to the `[[i]]` in the definition of `a`. How would I go about defining `a` outside of the loop while still extracting every value from the string? This may be obvious, but I am quite new to R, especially loops...

Comment: @RonakShah I can try!

Comment: I do not have an answer to that question as I'm unclear what you want. To me, it seems that you want to select something based on a split of a string which you read binary. First, I'm not sure if the selector accepts binary. Second, I'm pretty sure that the logic is not right since in the current code ```a``` is equal to the last iteration of the loop. Try to come up with a small example for lines 73-84. Then I'm sure @RonakShah or I can solve your issue.

Comment: @MacOS I have made an update that hopefully is helpful for you. Thank you for offering your help

Comment: @RonakShah I have made an update that hopefully is helpful for you. Thank you for offering your help

Comment: Thanks for that. I am not sure what is happening here. I got an error when I ran it for the first time and now it works fine for me and I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Instead of using `magicfor` you might want to take a look at `purrr::map_dfr()`.  `magicfor` uses some dark witchcraft that might be messing with your function (as `a` exists as a variable name and as a column in `values.df`, but that should not be a problem with `dplyr>1.0.0`).

Comment: @DanChaltiel Thanks for the suggestion! I will check that out. It does seem like the `magicfor` functions are causing my problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem in the future I will share the solution that worked for me:

My problem was in using functions from the `magicfor` package in my function. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409150/14779324) answer to another question I was able to change my `for` loop so that it works:

```
values.df <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:length(subsubsplit1)) {
    a <- readBin(as.raw(strtoi(apply(matrix(strsplit(subsubsplit1,"")[[i]],2),2,paste, collapse=""), 16)), "double", size=4)
    values.df <- rbind(values.df, data.frame(t(a), row.names = NULL))
  }

  colnames(values.df) <- "kcps"
```