# Code runs correctly but when written as a function it does not gives segmentatino fault

Tags: c++, function, vector

Currently I am trying to fill

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> vec
```

and I'm doing this using this part of code:

```
std::vector<char> tmp;
for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++){
    tmp.push_back('#');
}
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
    vec.push_back(tmp);
}
```

which works as intended when tested using:

```
std::cout << vec.size() << "\n";
std::cout << vec[0].size() << "\n";
```

(the output is:
10
10)
The problem comes when i try to make it into a function:

```
void fill(std::vector<std::vector<char>> v, char ch = 0x20) {
        std::vector<char> tmp;
        for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++){
            tmp.push_back(ch);
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
            v.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
```

when tested using:

```
fill(vec, '#');
std::cout << vec.size() << "\n";
std::cout << vec[0].size() << "\n";
```

I get a segmentation fault error, which looks like this:

```
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I suppose the 0 means the vector `vec` doesn't even get filled with the `tmp` vectors. I should also say that function `fill` is a member of a class in a separate file. I can provide it if necessary. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366588/code-works-on-its-own-but-not-as-a-function) but, unfortunately, it wasn't very helpful.

Comment: hint: if I write `void f(int i) {i = 7;}` and then call `f(x);` does it change x?

Comment: You passed the vector by value, which makes a copy.  You need to pass by reference: `void fill(std::vector<std::vector<char>> v, char ch = 0x20)` -> `void fill(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& v, char ch = 0x20)`

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<std::vector<char> > vec(10,std::vector<char>(10, '#'));`?

Answer (score 2):

Super common newbie error. When you want a function to calculate something, you should **return** the result from the function, not pass the result as a parameter.

Like this

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> fill(char ch = 0x20) {
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> v;
    ...
    return v;
}

vec = fill('#');
```

The alternative is to pass a reference to the result to the function

```
void fill(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& v, char ch = 0x20) {
    ...
}

fill(vec, '#');
```

Notice the extra `&` that's what turns `v` into a reference.

The first is preferable (IMHO) but many newbies prefer the second. I guess because it is closer to the code they tried to write in the first place.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply, appreciate it. I rewrote it and seems to work fine so thanks again.

Comment: its not just newbie/non-newbie or personal preference, but the two functions do something different. `void fill(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& v, char ch = 0x20) ` will add more elements to an already existing vector. The first can only create a new vector, not append to an existing one

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes that's a good point, another reason to prefer the fist (assuming adding to an existing vector was not the intent).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `vec[0].size()` is **undefined behavior** because you passed the vector **by value** and so `vec` is still an empty vector.

To solve this you can pass the vector by reference.

```
//--------------------------------------v----------------------->pass by reference
void fill(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& v, char ch = 0x20) {
    
}
```

---

Note also that you don't need to create and call a function as we can directly initialize the vector as shown below:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > vec(10,std::vector<char>(10, '#'))
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/P-awhV4v9)